# Mobile app friend invite/notification

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm currently developing a mobile app that allows the user to login through facebook. This allows the app to show which facebook friend is already using the app.

The next thing I want to do is to allow the user to send an invitation about the app to their others facebook friends who are not yet using the app. I've seen that many other applications do that by posting a message to the friend's wall. I think this approach is too intrusive. I like the aproach path is taking by sending a notification like it can be seen in the following screenshot.

[image]

What API call do I have to use to achieve this? I've been trying with [apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). but no luck so far.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find a way to post requests using graph api?

Answer (score 0):

Apprequests is the right way to do that but your request will only appear on facebook ios app, because you have only "connected" your IOS app in your facebook app parameters (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).
You need an app on facebook.com to make it work.